# SQL Server 2008 Management Studio open file dialog not responding

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-7-x64

I am having problems opening files in SQL Server Management Studio.

I can connect fine to the local database (SQL Server std. 2008 R2), but when I do File > Open > Open File, the dialog just hangs until it says 'Not Responding'.

It does eventually connect, but hangs for a period of 20-30 seconds to navigate between each folder on the local network.

I **do not** have the same problem navigating the same folders with windows explorer or Visual Studio 2012. It seems that this only occurs with SQL Server Management Studio.

I have tried to find a thread to find a resolution, but the only thread I did find had the link removed to the solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have any network share, remove it and try.

Probably, Open file dialog is stuck at one of the mapped drive?

Also, check https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20725/sql-server-management-studio-slow-opening-new-windows

Hope that helps.
PS: Have you installed latest SP?

Comment: One of the network shares was down so was causing issues - even though it wasn't the one that I was navigating to. It's funny how it's only SQL Server management server that throws a wobbler over this! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Windows 7 and SSMS 2008 and was also having this very frustrating problem, but only with SSMS.  I tried opening each of my mapped drives, and I disconnected any that had invalid paths.  No more problem!

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem, and I do have network shares. I upgraded SQL Server 2008 R2 to service pack 2. Now the problem is gone. I didn't have to touch my network shares.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, every time i click open file dialog for sql file, ssms just hangs and takes 30-40 seconds to respond. I uninstalled SQL Server 2005 32 bit on 64 bit windows 7 and installed 64 bit of SQL Server but the problem did not resolve.. I found there was a network drive unmapped, I deleted unmapped drive and problem resolved with no delays. I am surprised  how weird it is that unmapped drive can cause problem in sql server tools performance.

Answer (score 0):

I have an solution very easy:

1. Close the SSMS with the Task Manager.
2. Open again SSMS.
3. Solution:

   - Tray generate an script from any Database (only tray, until appear the Open File Dialog).
   - Close the Open File Dialog.
   - The problem is solved.
   - Now you can use the "Open File Dialog"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with SQL Server 2014sp1 not showing the File Browser dialog. Unmounting the SQL Server installation media in the Hyper-V manager for the VM solved the issue.